# mahout Spearmans Correlation java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, mahout

I'm using mahout `KMeansDriver` to build clusters, and want to use `Spearman` as `DistanceMeasure`.

Can I find this algorithm in java or do I need to write it myself?

I didn't find any examples for that on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not use k-means with other distance measures.

### It may stop converging.

K-means is *designed* to **minimize variance**. Your distance function must also minimize variance, otherwise you lose the convergence property. For guaranteed convergence with other distances, see partitioning around medoids (PAM) aka k-medoids.

Correlation measures are a good example of distances that do *not* work with k-means:

Consider the two vectors, and absolute spearman correlation: dist=1-|r|

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

Obviously, spearman correlation is -1, and these two vectors are considered "identical".

However, k-means will now compute the **mean** of these two, which yields the constant vector

```
3 3 3 3 3
```

which is as dis-similar to these two (in fact, it's correlation with anything isn't even well defined). In other words: **the mean does not minimize absolute correlation**, and
you shouldn't use this distance function.

#### Variance = squared Euclidean

This is why you should be using k-means only with squared Euclidean distance.

#### On L2 normalized vectors: Variance ~ Cosine

This is easy to see when looking at the definition of cosine similarity, and the reason why *spherical* k-means also works.

Comment: Can you cite some examples-docs of the approach you are mentioning?

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids and Kaufman, L. and Rousseeuw, P.J. (1987). K-means and k-medoids are really ancient by data analysis standards...